# Run UITests without build app

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, uitest

So, the question is how to run ui tests on real device with already installed app. 
I have a preconfigured build on my real device and want to run uitests on this build, without building new app, only run tests. 
Is it real?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, unfortunately - this is not possible. App has to be rebuilt and (re)installed before running test classes.